# Debian boot disc with a gnu zebra

Tags: linux, debian, installation, boot

How can i build a debian boot disc with GNU Zebra installed on it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably have to build your own.  Debian has a guide that describes how to build a *live* environment. http://live.debian.net/manual/

Answer (score 0):

Also Zebra is long obsolete, you should use its replacement, [Quagga](http://www.quagga.net/).